# Hibernate @EmbeddedId's behaviour

Tags: java, hibernate

I was going through some tutorials on Hibernate, and I came across one scenario in which a primary key can be a compound (like 2-3 fields taken together form primary key). As per my understanding, this is achievable using @EmbeddedId annotation.

I tried to do this using simple application.

## UserObj  Object:

```
package com.vipin.model;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class UserObj {

private int userId;
private String userName;
private String SSN;

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getSSN() {
    return SSN;
}
public void setSSN(String sSN) {
    SSN = sSN;
}   
}
```

****UPDATE*****

## UserModel which uses UserObj as Compound primary key:

```
@Entity(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class UserModel implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private UserObj userObj;

@Id
@Column(name="USER_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int userId;

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public UserObj getUserObj() {
    return userObj;
}
public void setUserObj(UserObj userObj) {
    this.userObj = userObj;
}
```

## Main application/ demo application:

```
package com.vipin.mainapplication;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.vipin.model.UserModel;
import com.vipin.model.UserObj;

public class HibernateMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
    UserObj userObj = new UserObj(); //Demo of Primary key which is an object.

    userObj.setUserId(1);
    userObj.setUserName("VIPIN KOUL");
    userObj.setSSN("000001");
    userModel.setUserObj(userObj); //Demo of Primary key which is an object.

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(userModel);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
}
}
```

However when I run this program, i am able to save the data into DB, even though i supply the same values for all these fields.  With @EmbeddedId, isn't hibernated supposed to check that it doesn't allow to save this object into DB if same object exists in DB (i.e. duplicate values not allowed).

Do we need to enforce anything on DB side as well? I am under the impression that this annotation is going to check.

Any clues greatly appreciated.

## ***UPDATE****

I missed to include one more piece of code in UserModel:

```
@Id
@Column(name="USER_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int userId;
```

With this, hibernate was taking the combination of these four coloumns as primary key, and so no exception.

I removed this field and when i run the program second time (with same values), it throw the exception.

Hence, in conclusion @EmbeddedId does enforce primary key in case we have compound primary key.

Comment: Is your database generated by Hibernate?

Comment: The restriction should be on DB also, you should have coposite key. Hibernate is just inserting the record in your DB table, it means you are not having proper composite key defined on your table.

Comment: Yes, first time for DB creation. And subsequent run as "update" (so that previous values are retained).

Comment: @PredragMaric: Issue resolved, have updated it.

Comment: Great, glad you worked it out.